# Как получить id юзера в telegram (pyTelegramBotAPI)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, telebot

Задача такая, нужно получить id юзера в телерам и сравнить его с другими idшниками, котороые хранятся в другом файле. Пытался использовать следующий код:

```py
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: 'X' == mess.text or 'Y' == mess.text, content_types=['text'])
    def handle_text(message):
user_id = str(message)  #получаем инофрмацию о пользователе
user_id = user_id[64 : 73]  #извлекаем только user id
filename = "D:\bot\wtf.txt"
with open(filename) as users_id
if user_id in users_id:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы в списке")
else:
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вы не в списке")
```

В wtf.txt есть нужные id, но почему то всегда срабатывает блок else:
Использую pyTelegramBotAPI

1. Как получить ТОЛЬКО id юзера?
2. Как правильно реализовать сравнение?

Comment: idшник можно вытащить с помощью user_id = message.from_user.id
но второй вопрос всё ёщё актуален. Как реализовать сравнение с данным в текстовом файле и добавление соответственно?

Comment: Пробовали через цикл?

Answer (score 1):

Есть всем известный модуль requests, с которым все сделать намного проще,
ссылка на статью [вот](https://proglib.io/p/telegram-bot/), и ссылка на пример [вот](https://ramziv.com/matter-detail/7), а для сравнения можно сохранять id пользователей в json файл (конечно файлик то разорвется если будет много запросов)

```
import requests

url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot<token>/"

def get_updates_json(request):  
    response = requests.get(request + 'getUpdates')
    return response.json()

def last_update(data):  
    telega= data['result']
    total_updates = len(telega) - 1
    results =  telega[total_updates]['message']['from']
    print(f"id :{results['id']}, Имя: {results['first_name']}")

last_update(get_updates_json(url))
```

Comment: Хорошо бы основное в ответ перенести.